# How can i visit my angular cli website with routes?

Tags: angular

I have a website which I made with the angular cli. And I'm using routes to switch the content.
My problem is, when i type e.g: `www.website.de/login` it give me an error: `404 Not Found`. I run this website with `http-server . -p 80`. I have all `ng build --prog` files (dist) on the server. But if i try that local with `ng serve` and i type: `localhost:4200/login` it works.

Here are my files that are importent:

`index.html`

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <home></home>
    <script src="assets/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

`home.component.html`

```
<header>
    <navbar></navbar>
</header>
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
<footer *ngIf="router.url != '/dashboard'" class="page-footer">
    <footer-footer></footer-footer>
</footer>
```

`app-routing.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

import {DashboardComponent} from "./Dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {ImprintComponent} from "./Imprint/imprint.component";
import {ContactUsComponent} from "./ContactUs/contactus.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "./Login/login.component";
import {StartComponent} from "./start/start.component";
import {ImpressumComponent} from "./Impressum/impressum.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', component: StartComponent },
    { path: 'imprint', component: ImprintComponent },
    { path: 'impressum', component: ImpressumComponent },
    { path: 'contact_us', component: ContactUsComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{ }
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardComponent } from "./Dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import {NavbarComponent} from "./Navbar/navbar.component";
import {ImprintComponent} from "./Imprint/imprint.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./Home/home.component";
import {ContactUsComponent} from "./ContactUs/contactus.component";
import {LoginComponent} from "./Login/login.component";
import {FooterFooter} from "./Footer/footer.component";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import { StartComponent } from './start/start.component';
import {ImpressumComponent} from "./Impressum/impressum.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      DashboardComponent,
      NavbarComponent,
      ImprintComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      ContactUsComponent,
      LoginComponent,
      FooterFooter,
      StartComponent,
      ImpressumComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Regards

Comment: so did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920482/2545680) help?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ng serve` angular-cli uses under the hood webpack-dev-server which is pre-configured to redirect every request to the `index.html` file. That's why it works when you type `www.website.de/login`. It does redirect and returns `index.html`, then Angular starts and pick ups the current URL and performs routing.

Now, when you use your custom server, like `http-server`, it doesn't do that. You have to configure the redirect yourself. Unfortunately, there [is no easy way to do that](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/373) for `http-server`.

I suggest you use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) for static files instead of `http-server`. It has a simple API for configuring redirects using [middleware](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#custom-routes-example).